# Where is the Laravel 5.3 equivalent of AuthController.php located?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on the User Authentication portion of a Laravel 5.3 project and if I am not mistaken in a previous version AuthController.php was in Auth folder, but in the 5.3 version it is no longer there.

I am looking to change the home page that appears from the default homepage that comes with doing:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

to the homepage I had prior to doing

```
php artisan make:auth
```

after a user is registered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the AuthController was broken into two separate controllers in Laravel 5.3.

You should now have:
*app/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php*
and
*app/Controller/Auth/RegisterController.php*

You'll want to set the **$redirectTo** attribute of each separately.

Hope this helps!

Comment: so you provided the correct answer and I will check it off, but I am in a bit of a conundrum now because when I login a user it does go to the homepage I created, but if I were to click on the login link on the menu again, it will redirect me to the Auth templated login page and I think thats because in my layouts/main.blade.php side-nav have the a href="/login", so its like I am calling the Auth template login. Does that make sense?

Comment: Right, so you probably want to adjust your menu's login link based on if the current user is logged in or not; if she is logged in, you put a logout link instead...

You can check if the current user is logged-in in your blade template with @if(Auth::check())

Answer (score 1):

It's the same in Laravel version 5.6 - two files, I struggled for a few minutes to figure it out as well, basically I would guess one of the reasons for spiting the **AuthController.php** into two files (**LoginController.php** and **RegisterController.php**) is that you may want to customize things in more detail, for example, redirect users who just registered to one location and redirect existing users to another location, after they login.

Both files are inside:

```
app\Http\Controllers\Auth
```

[image]